# I can't seem to change drive drive using attached piece of code

Tags: command-line, batch-file

```
y: &pause
cd ptls5.0 &pause
sdp describe Integration.dpk &pause
z: &pause
cd ptls5.0 &pause
dir &pause
```

I have those commands in the 1.cmd file. First three are executed fine. The result of it is that after "sdp describe Integration.dpk &pause" is executed I'm given "press any key to continue..." after I hit any key. The command prompt quits. Instead of changing drive to z:>. What is  wrong with it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I'm truly sorry to have messed up your edit! Go ahead, I won't interfere again.

Comment: @Konrad - no worries, your edit was better anyway!

Answer (score 3):

If sdp is a .cmd or .bat file, change it to "call sdp....."

Answer (score 1):

Is "sdp" another batch file itself? If so, you will need to use `call`:

```
call sdp describe Integration.dpk &pause
```